# Troubling generating a random order from an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, random

total newbie here. I've written a program in java to help randomize the order of bands for a concert I'm organizing. I'm having trouble getting the code to work. The output I get terminates after printing three strings instead of four, often repeats strings (which I don't want) and terminates after the third string with the following error:

"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive"

Can anyone help troubleshoot my code?

```
public class BandRandomizer
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<String> bands = new ArrayList<>();
    bands.add("Band A");
    bands.add("Band B");
    bands.add("Band C");
    bands.add("Band D");

    Random gen = new Random();
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        index = gen.nextInt(i);
        System.out.println(bands.get(index));
        bands.remove(i);    
    }



}
```

}

Comment: How about `Collections.shuffle()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting an exception thrown in the last loop as you are calling `nextInt(0)`:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive
>           at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:388)

Should be:

```
for (int i = 4; i > 0; i--) { //changed
    index = gen.nextInt(i); // return value in range [0..i) perfect for indexing
    System.out.println(bands.get(index));
    bands.remove(index); //changed
}
```

You can also `remove` and `get` in one fell swoop as `remove` returns the removed item:

```
System.out.println(bands.remove(index));
```

But this is a bad way of shuffling, use `Collections.shuffle`:

```
Collections.shuffle(bands);
for (String band : bands) {
    System.out.println(band);
}
```

Comment: You're totally right about the index and i mix up -- and then with the i=4 as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use `Collection.shuffle()`. But if you don't want to use stuff in the JDK or you want to know where did you do wrong, here are your mistakes.

There are two places that you need to fix.

`Random.nextInt(x)` returns a random integer that is between 0 and x - 1. Therefore, your `i` should go from 4 to 1:

```
for (int i = 4; i >= 1; i--)
```

The last line in the for loop is incorrect. I think what you are trying to do here is to delete the band that has been selected. The band that has been selected is not at index `i`, but at index `index`. Therefore, change the last line to:

```
bands.remove(index);
```

An alternative approach would be to only loop from 4 to 2 and print the remaining item in the array list. I think this approach is faster.

Comment: "alternative approach would be to only loop from 4 to 2 and print the remaining item" But they would definitely still be in order, unless I don't understand what you're suggesting.

Comment: @weston yeah I might not have explained this well. What I mean is to keep the op's existing code but change the for loop to loop from 4 to 2 because `nextInt(1)` always returns 1.

Comment: returns `0` but yeah I see

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code. It works for your problem.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ArrayList<String> bands = new ArrayList<>();
    bands.add("Band A");
    bands.add("Band B");
    bands.add("Band C");
    bands.add("Band D");
    int i=1;
    Collections.shuffle(bands);
    for(String band: bands){

        System.out.println(i++ + ". " +band);
    }

}
```

The reason why you are getting Exception is: value of nextInt argument must be greater than zero.

```
public int nextInt(int n) {
   if (n <= 0)
     throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be positive");

   if ((n & -n) == n)  // i.e., n is a power of 2
     return (int)((n * (long)next(31)) >> 31);

   int bits, val;
   do {
       bits = next(31);
       val = bits % n;
   } while (bits - val + (n-1) < 0);
   return val;
 }
```

Comment: What's with the `i++ + ". " +`?

Comment: it is just to show the sequence. i++ increnments the value. You can directly use System.out.println(band); if it is not required to print sequence.